# java chat sending users list from server to clients and update it

Tags: java, serialization, client-server, chat, jlist

I write client-server chat using sockets. Help me please understand how send the list of current registered users from server to clients and update it when list changed. I read [this similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7295569/java-chat-server-see-online-accounts) but steel don't understand how to do it. I used **BufferedReader** and **PrintWriter** streams for sending and receiving messages. And I don't want sending the list of the users any time when clients send messages.

I keep list of users in a map as a key set on the server side.

```
public class Server{
    private final Map<String, ServerThread> clients = Collections.synchronizedMap(new TreeMap<>());
    //.....
}
```

I read on one forum, if use serialization, than all serializable classes have to be both the sending and the receiving side. But I don't need server class on client side.

**UPDATE:**
If I will use **ObjectOutputStream / ObjectInputStream** instead **BufferedReader** and **PrintWriter** whether the following approach is useful for distinguishing messages from the list of user names?

```
//code on client side:
Object received = input.readObject();
if (received instanceof List) {
    List<String> users = (List) received;
    //display users in JList
} else if (received instanceof String) {
    String message = (String) received;
    //display in JTextArea
}
```

Comment: You have to make up some protocol to distinguish between messages and user lists.

Comment: Can you give me an example or link to read?